# Numpy RuntimeWarning inconsistent with array length 1

Tags: python, numpy

Why is a `RuntimeWarning` thrown for a comparison against `np.nan` (or `math.nan`) only when the array length is greater than 1?

```
In [34]: np.array([np.nan]) > 0
Out[34]: array([False])

In [35]: np.array([np.nan, 5]) > 0
/usr/local/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7
Out[35]: array([False,  True])
```

I would expect the behavior to be consistent. The `np.greater` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html) don't mention behavior specific to `nan`. I have disabled these warnings with `np.seterr(invalid='ignore')` but I don't understand the inconsistency.

Numpy 1.15.0, Python 3.7.0, IPython 6.5.0

Comment: I get a runtime warning for `np.array([np.nan]) > 0`. That's with `1.13.3`.

Comment: Very strange. No warning in 1.15.0. Admittedly, this isn't a huge issue. More of 'wtf?' moment I was hoping to find an answer to...

Comment: There is some discussion on [github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7352) but it doesn't look like anything has been taken forward. Pretty much your exact observation was also raised [later on](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9382)

Comment: numpy version 1.15.4: RuntimeWarning is thrown in both cases.